# Grid with GridSplitter is resized incorrectly when resizing the main window

Tags: c#, wpf, window-resize, gridsplitter

I Have a wpf window which can be resized:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTester.BadResize"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="BadResize"
        Height="300"
        Width="600"
        MinWidth="600">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="250" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Left Panel" />

        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"
                      ResizeDirection="Columns"
                      Width="3"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

        <TextBox Grid.Column="2"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 Text="Test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text text test text test text test text" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This window has a grid with left and right panels and a GridSplitter between them.
I run the program:
[image]

Then I do the following steps:

1. Resize the right window border to the right to allow the text to fit the textbox without word wrap
   [image]
2. Move the GridSpliiter to the most left (this step is important)
   [image]
3. Start resizing the right window border back to the left. It works ok and the textbox is resized perfectly as long as the text fits the textbox
   [image]
4. Once the text doesn't fit the textbox and word wrap is required the textbox stops resizing and goes outside the window this way:
   [image]

Could you please help me to figure out how to arrange layout with grid splitter the way that textbox will not go outside the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after many experiments Wrap only works with GridSplitter for me if there is another element (with non-zero margin) to measure column width and bind that value to TextBox.Width

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="250"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Left Panel" Name="lbl"/>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

    <Border Grid.Column="2" Name="test" Margin="0.05"/>

    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" 
            Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=test, Mode=OneWay}"
            TextWrapping="Wrap"
            Text="Test1 text2 test3 text4 test5 text6 test7 text8 test9 text0 test1 text2 test3 text4 test5 text6 test7 text8 text9 test0 text1 test2 text3 test4 text5" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yes, it works. However, if you have, lets say, 8-10 textboxes or textblocks in the second column of this grid, resizing becomes extremelly slow because FormatLine function takes much time when layout is organized this way. Just copy and paste the same 10 textboxes, wrap them in some grid, run the app, move the GridSpliiter to the most left and try bo resize the window. It becomes slow only if you move the GridSpliiter to the most left. Seems to be a bug in WPF.

Comment: I have just tried (with UniformGrid and 20+ TextBoxes) but cannot say it became slow. I used `Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=test, Mode=OneWay}"` on UniformGrid

Comment: Thanks so much for this. This Border workaround solved a similar GridSplitter resize blocking problem I was having with a TextBox inside a **DockPanel**. Also surprising that it definitely needs a non-zero Margin (I had better results setting Margin to "1"). With the smaller "0.05" setting, I could trigger an "animated move" of the GridSplitter if I clicked it and dragged right far enough.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't make a column for your gridsplitter. Keep it in the same column as one of you elements. That way is it more predictable, and you know which columns it is resizing.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="250" />
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Left Panel" Margin="0,0,3,0"/>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0"
                  ResizeDirection="Columns"
                  Width="3"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />

    <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             Text="Test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text text test text test text test text" />
</Grid>
```

I guess it will make more sense to set the first Columns width to AUTO, but of of course try it your self and see what fits better.

Comment: I agree it looks better but works the same way as I described in the question.

Comment: You probably missed step 2 Move the GridSpliiter to the most left.

Comment: Well, I did.. it still works.. but as I mentioned in my answer I use: `<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="250" />`

Comment: No, it's not cool. When the first column definition width is Auto, the first column is not resized when you resize the main window border. That is why I definitely need column definition width to be "*".

Comment: But ok, now I tried with the *. And It still wraps. Do you still have 3 columns or did you use the code I provided ? It definitely works the way you want with the code I provided.

Comment: I just copied your code and it works exactly the way I described in the question.

Comment: Yes, i did too and it doesnt fix the problem. It seems something to do with Width="*" MinWidth="250", but no idea how to fix it